# nx --platform not selecting platform

Tags: ionic-framework, devops, nomachine-nx

I'm busy with some devops so I need everything to run in terminal

However, running the below command still brings up the prompt to select the platform and blocks any further execution.

> nx run myProject:add --platform android

[image]

Any one having this issue?

Comment: if it is ionic project try command: `ionic cordova platform add android` if using cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation was incorrect

fixed it with

> nx run myProject:add:android